# Sound is distorted (slow effect) after installing Intel HD Graphics drivers on Intel NUC

Tags: sound, 15.10, intel-graphics, intel-nuc

Having Intel NUC model NUC5i5RYK with Ubuntu 15.10 on board. Installed Intel HD Graphics through [Intel Graphics Installer For Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads). After it I have tested sound through display port. The sound is horrible. It is distorted with something like slow effect. Besides it is fixed after rebooting system, but after some time this bug appears again. The sound through audio port works fine. Is there some way to fix it?

Comment: The version of Intel Graphics Installer For Linux is 1.4.0.

Comment: Did you ever solve this as I have the same issue